# Need to stop an exception causing transaction to fail

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails 2.3.9 code, an exception can be thrown but this should not cause the transaction to fail.

The flow is `ServiceA.serviceA()` calls `ServiceB.serviceB()` indirectly via another few services. `ServiceB.serviceB()` throws the exception. Several other services call `ServiceB.serviceB()` but I only want to the Transaction to not fail when is calling it.

This is what I have tried:

1. Mark `ServiceA.serviceA()` marked with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[MyException.class])`
2. Above with `ServiceA` marked with `static transactional=false`

Neither work.

I also try:

1. The above with also `ServiceB.serviceB()` marked with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[MyException.class])`
2. All the above with also `ServiceB` marked with `static transactional=false`

To test this, I am running a spock integration test. To ensure the integration test is transactional, I `static transactional = false` at the top of the integration test.

The only way I managed to get this to work is to make every service in between ServiceA and ServiceB as `static transactional = false`

Otherwise I see:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure15_closure16.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:165)
```

Is this the only solution?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the intended functionality here. Do you intend on having BEGIN TRANSACTION ServiceA call -> Call X services including ServiceB -> Exception -> More Calls -> COMMIT TRANSACTION? Meaning you do want a transaction, and for the transaction to commit even with an exception in the middle?

Comment: It is using the Open Session In View pattern in Grails. Which turns on the Transaction at beginning and end by default.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Have you tried marking the methods you don't want to participate in the transaction as @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) As this will suspend the transaction for these methods.